# Dynamic Meta for Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, meta-tags, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

Can anyone help with a situation regarding meta info with dynamic data.

**Problem**

We are using Nuxt and generate our static page using npm run generate, and have identified several problems with this approach:

- open graph and twitter meta tags can't be dynamically updated because
  crawlers don't run JS
- details page during build process is generated    only once and
  therefore doesn't have any relevant data until user has    navigated
  to that page with URL parameters (e.g.
  example.com/cars/details?make=Audi&model=A6&carID=133852) which then 
  feed AJAX GET request for data

**Desired outcome**

Open graphs, twitter and other meta tags unique for every car details page.

**Question**

Is it possible to achieve the desired outcome with generated static only? If not what would the process look like with SSR or server side generated meta content?

Our dist folder structure is currently:

```html
dist/
  ├ index.html
  ├ cars/
    ├ index.html
    └ details/
      ├ index.html
      └ payment/
        └ index.html
```

**cars** page with a list of cars

**details** clicking a car navigates to details page of the selected car

**payment** car purchase page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67746983/localization-meta-tags-for-seo-in-nuxt-ssr-fixed-in-source-code-just-plugin

Answer (score 23):

No, it won't be possible to provide dynamic meta tags while serving pre-rendered static HTML.

Running Nuxt in [universal](https://nuxtjs.org/guide#server-rendered-universal-ssr-) mode makes it possible to fetch page data from API (via [fetch](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch#the-fetch-method), [asyncData](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data#the-asyncdata-method) or [nuxtServerInit action](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-nuxtserverinit-action)), generate HTML content of the page (including dynamic meta tags) and serve it to the user.

Simple usage example with SSR:

```js
export default {
    async asyncData({ query, store }) {
        const { make, model, cardID } = query;
        // Validate query params

        // fetch data from API
        try {
            const carDetails = await store.dispatch('getCardInfo', {
                make,
                model,
                cardID,
            });
            return {
                cardDetails,
            };
        } catch (error) {
            // Redirect to error page or 404 depending on server response
        }
    },
    head() {
        return {
            title: this.carDetails.title,
            meta: [
                {
                    hid: 'og-title',
                    property: 'og:title',
                    content: this.carDetails.title,
                },
                // other meta
            ],
        };
    },
};
```

This will ensure that page data is loaded before component has been rendered and valid meta tags will be included for search engines consumption.

Sidenote: rather than using query params, you may want to check [dynamic routes](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#dynamic-routes), which are significantly better for SEO, as well as user friendly URL (e.g. `example.com/cars/audi/a6/133852`)

Comment: Thx for the response, I will try that!
Great sidenote! but I was thinking about this structure for link `example.com/cars/detail/audi-a6-2018-133852`, in Your opinion, would that be ok, or google would like your solution better?

Comment: At this point it would not matter for SEO, as long as query parameters aren't used. It is a good solution with less nesting. If you don't have plans to create standalone pages `/cars/audio`, `/cars/opel/astra`, then your solution is a good option. Just an advice: provide slug `audi-a6-2018-133852` from back-end, so you can query cars by `slug`, instead of parsing strings separated by dashes. This will reduce error for querying automobiles.